# Editor post counter blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I wonder is it possible to show number of post posted by editor I have other editor with me on blogger so I want to show under every editor the number of post he posted.
 like this image below

[image: xxx Post counter xxx]

Comment: Yes, it's possible, by writing the number of posts in HTML next to the image of the poster and using [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) to move that text over the image. If you want more detailed answers, you should show us the code you have tried first.

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm trying to say is if there is a code or html tag or any other things like jquery code to automatically count posts per editor  . So Is it possible ?

Comment: I see, so this is mainly a question about how to read the right value from the Blogger platform, not how to display it once you have it. I can't help with that, but maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a solution, you could add a Blog Widget and calculate the post like in this demo. 
In this solution you need to "hardcode" the Author Names(here for the Demo `Author1` and `Author2`).

```
<b:widget id='Blog2' locked='false' title='Blogposts' type='Blog' >
  <b:includable id='main'>
    <script>
      <b:with var='firstAuthorPosts' value='data:posts filter (p =&gt; p.author.name == &quot;Author1&quot;)'>
         var author1 = <data:firstAuthorPosts.size />;
       </b:with>    
       <b:with var='secondAuthorPosts' value='data:posts filter (p =&gt; p.author.name == &quot;Author2&quot;)'>
         var author2 = <data:secondAuthorPosts.size />;
       </b:with>    
       window.addEventListener("load", function(){
         // here write this info into the HTML
         alert(`Author 1 has: ${author1} Posts and Author 2 has: ${author2} Posts`);
       });
     </script>
  </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

to add the Post to the HTML you would have to use some javascript, but how this is done depends on the HTML your template generates.

> Here a lambda function is used to `filter` posts from specific Auhtor and the get the amount with the `size` Post - Array Metadata.
>   *(It is done twice since it is for two Authors)*
>   the `window.addEvnetListener` Event is added, to write the Data into the alert (in your case then the HTML-DOM)

More detailed information to the used Blogger Syntax can be found here: [Unofficial Documentation](http://template-data.blogspot.co.at/2017/05/posts.html)

**Update:**
Javascript Details

- `<b:with var='firstAuthorPosts'` ... creates a variable with the name `firstAuthorPosts`
- `... value='...'>` ... set's the value of the variable
- `data:posts` ... blog-widget-variable for all posts.
- `filter` ... is a lambda function for arrays, that returns only elements, where the past in function returns true
- `(p =&gt; p.author.name == &quot;Author1&quot;)` ... is the function, that will be executed for each element in the array, and returns only

So `<b:with var='firstAuthorPosts' value='data:posts filter (p =&gt; p.author.name == &quot;Author1&quot;)'>` creates a variable and sets the value to all posts of the author with the name `Author1`.

- `<data:firstAuthorPosts.size />` ... returns the size/count of all posts in the array `firstAuthorPosts`

So `var author1 = <data:firstAuthorPosts.size />;` creates a javascript variable, that will be set to the count of all posts of the author `Author1`.

*The following three lines, are the same for the `Author2`*

- creates a load eventHandler, for when the Website is loaded
  `` window.addEventHandler("load", function(){ 
  alert(`Author 1 has: ${author1} Posts and Author 2 has: ${author2} Posts`);
  }); ``

***Since the Javascript variables `author1` and `author2`, are global the can be accessed in the event function.***

This line is just to show, how to access the values:
`` alert(`Author 1 has: ${author1} Posts and Author 2 has: ${author2} Posts`); ``

It uses Interpolation thats why the `${author1}` and `${author2}`. ([Documentation to Javascript interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

Comment: Can you explain the last part of javascript please ??

Comment: @YoussefMajbri is the javascript part now clear? Or is there some part you would like to know?

Comment: All clear, but how can I put all pieces together in blogger widget?

Comment: @YoussefMajbri that depends on your code. It was to long for an answer so I wrote an blog entry https://leesflamelayout.blogspot.co.at/2017/08/how-to-add-post-count-to-your-profile.html. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you a lot for all you've done to make it clear for me and for others, thank you so much

Comment: can you give me the blogger template code ? for develop purpose

Comment: @YoussefMajbri it is the default contempo theme, with the code of the Blog. but here you can download it. I will leave this link up until friday https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0BzikaQtufvN9RHR0X0w3aV9CQ0E