# Number of posts by aurthor Blogger

Tags: javascript, lambda, blogger

I've ask before and get incomplete answer or miss understanding from me because I don't have any knowledge in JS so I wish you help me with this.
Thanks to winner_joiner for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368702/8265400).

---

and I've read what he mention so I cannot understand it, and what figure out is I have to use  Lambda function which use loop as blogger use,So this what I found :

```
<b:loop var='post' values='data:posts filter (post => post.author == "Aurthor1")'>
<!--what can I edit here to make sure everything goes well-->
      </b:loop>
```

And how can I set it in blogger .

Comment: the lambda function `filter`  "loops" internally over the posts, you don't have use `<b:loop..` tag, for filtering. So `<b:loop var='post' values='data:posts filter (post => post.author == "Aurthor1")'>` will only loop over the posts of the `Author1`.

Comment: What excatly do you want to achieve? How should the output look like? (P.s.: I updated my post, with some more explanation) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368702/1679286

Comment: Great, I understand but how can I put it all together in one piece ?

Comment: I wrote a post to your question i hope this helps https://leesflamelayout.blogspot.co.at/2017/08/how-to-add-post-count-to-your-profile.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editor post counter blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222194/editor-post-counter-blogger)